# Dividing PNG into layers (HTML5, JS)

Tags: javascript, html, png, layer

I'm working for a small non commercial project, what I'm stuck on right now is that the script picks up a png image, however when I exported it, there are two layers, how do I divide this image into two different layers and manipulate one once its loaded up into convas?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function startup() {
            var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = 'brushes.png';
            img.onload = function() {
                ctx.translate(32, 120);
                ctx.rotate(40 * Math.PI/180);
                ctx.drawImage(img, -32, -120, 64, 120);
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload='startup();'>
    <canvas id="canvas" style="position: absolute; left: 300px; top: 300px;" width="800" height="800"></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: PNG doesn't support layers. I guess that you see layers in your image processing software - but once you save that image as a PNG file the layers will be gone, just a single plain image. If you want to access the image parts separately you probably want to put them one below the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know PNG does not have any layers, so you would need to save one image for each layer to manipulate them separately.

Comment: Thank you, forgot that illustrator ads extra data to 'enable' layers